# Will the openshifts free plan handle a small commercial application?

Tags: openshift, paas

Openshift does not offer paid plans for my country, so I would like to know if its free plans are capable of handling a small commercial application. 
I'm already aware of the limits from the free plan (about 15 page requests/sec, etc), but I'm quite new on this field so I don't have many metrics to compare with. 
If you guys think I need some service with a paid plan, could you recommend me another ones? I have tried Heroku, but I didn't like it. And GAE seems to be pretty locked in with its database and stuff.

--edit

I'm also considering making my code scalable, and using all the 3 free gears.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that many of Google's apps are built on the top of GAE (GMail, developers.google.com, etc) so the database is not that locked if you think about it when you have the right approach. If you still don't think it can handle some of the requirements you have you can take a look at [CloudSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) (which is simply a MySQL instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the free plan should handle a 'small' commercial application, depending on what you actual mean by that.  It might be worth your time to spin up the application on OpenShift then use a tool like Apache Benchmark to do some load testing to see if you get the results that you think you should based on the traffic that you are guessing that your application will get.